# Mid-document header/footer changes and reversions

Tags: header-footer, scrlayer-scrpage

Is it possible to set the scrlayer-scrpage header/footer in the preamble
change it mid-document, 
then return it to the original?

One such example, below, 
is the suppression of the header and footer on various starting pages. 
In the example, I do not know how to bring the original back.

**MWE**:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\cfoot{\normalfont \thepage}


\begin{document}


\pagestyle{empty}
A

\clearpage


\chapter{chapterName}
A

\clearpage


\pagestyle{myheadings}
A
\clearpage


A


\end{document}
```

Comment: Isn't usage of `\pagestyle` with (self-defined) different pagestyles exactly meant for this?

Comment: Ooh! Just read about this (because you mentioned it). TIL. I have never actually heard of this. Going to try now.  : j

Comment: According to [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Page_Layout), Section: Page Styles, there are 4 options to remove the headers/foots in some way, but none to go back to normal (or does myheadings include the footer too?).

Comment: No dice. `\pagestyle{empty} \input{./Subfiles/00-titlePage.tex} \input{./Subfiles/01-signaturePageElectronic.tex} \input{./Subfiles/02-abstract.tex} \pagestyle{myheadings}` still has page numbers in the `abstract.tex`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Alright - seems to be due to my first use of \chapter. (Any suggestions to masking page even after the first use of chapter?)

Comment: You cannot trust that particular page of the wikibook. Many strange and wrong information there.

Comment: I do not really understand what you exactly expect and what doesn't work. Nevertheless, I've tried to give an answer. Hope it's useful.

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Customizing_Page_Headers_and_Footers

Comment: @Johannes_B This is also not the best information source, if someone uses a KOMA-Script class.

Comment: @Schweinebacke That is the very same information,  i split that to a page of its own and added the two banners on top as well as https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Talk:LaTeX/Customizing_Page_Headers_and_Footers.

Comment: The wikibook is doomed right at that spot where memoir and KOMA come into place. It makes it just too complicated to mention what to choose and when to choose. It is a nightmare.

Answer (score 4):

The first page of a chapter always uses the page style defined by `\chapterpagestyle` (see the KOMA-Script manual, `scrguien.pdf`). So the `\pagestyle{empty}` does not change the page style of the first page of a chapter. But `scrlayer-scrpage` provides command `\newpairofpagestyles` to define a new pair of `headings` and `plain` page style. The default setting of both are empty head and empty foot.

So if you do not want head and foot at a portion of your document, you can use:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}% use running heads (see scrguien.pdf)
\setkomafont{pagenumber}{\normalfont}% print page numbers in \normalfont (see scrguien.pdf)
\newpairofpagestyles{trueempty}{}% define a new but empty pair of page styles headings and plain

\begin{document}


\pagestyle{trueempty}% Do not use head and foot even for plain pages
                     % (e.g. begin of chapter)
A

\clearpage


\chapter{chapterName}
A

\clearpage


\pagestyle{scrheadings}% Do use head and foot and also page numbers for plain pages (default page styles after loading scrlayer-scrpage)
A
\clearpage

A

\end{document}
```

[image][image]

In this example *two* new page styles are defined: `trueempty` and `plain.trueempty`. Both are empty page styles. `\pagestyle{trueempty}` not only switches to page style `trueempty` but also aliases `headings` to `trueempty` and `plain` to `plain.trueempty`. The default of `\chapterpagestyle` is still `plain`, so the `\thispagestyle{\chapterpagestyle}` of `\chapter` does switch to `plain.trueempty` which is an empty page style too.

The `\pagestyle{scrheadings}` switches back to page style `scrheadings`, the default page style after loading `scrlayer-scrpage`. And it also aliases `plain` back to `plain.scrheadings`, the default plain page style after loading `scrlayer-scrpage`. So it is enough to switch back to the defaults.

But if you only want to remove the footer/page number of the first page of a chapter, you can just use `\cfoot[]{\pagemark}`. To switch back to the default, `\cfoot*{\pagemark}` should be enough. And if you want to remove the page head and footer of every first page of a chapter, try `\renewcommand{\chapterpagestyle}{empty}`. The default would be `\renewcommand{\chapterpagestyle}{plain}`.

Comment: What does automark do (and marking in general)?

Comment: It appears that it applies the chapter name to the header.  Additionally, `\setkomafont{pagenumber}{\normalfont}` is equivalent to `\cfoot{\normalfont \thepage}`, because the default footer is `\thepage`, yes?

Comment: @kano: Read options `automark` and `manualmark` and commands `\automark` and `\manualmark` in the KOMA-Script manual, `scrguien.pdf` or `scrguide.pdf`, for information about automatic and manual running head. Read commands `\pagemark` and `\setkomafont` and `\addtokomafont` and element `pagenumber` in the manual for information about the page number formatting. You should not change the font manually. You should use the interface.

Comment: Noted; changed accordingly.